# implementing sudoku XV board

Tags: java, sudoku

I have found out the solution for standard sudoku however I do not know what to do with sudoku xv.
A Sudoku XV puzzle consists of a standard Sudoku grid with the addition of X and V markers between neighbouring pairs of squares. X markers show all adjacent pairs of squares where the two values in those squares add up to 10, while V markers show all pairs where the two values sum to 5.

I have developed simple sudoku, however, I need help implementing x and v markers between neighbouring pairs of squares

package n.sudoku_cnf;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
*
*
*/
public class Sudoku_CNF_Solution {

```
static final int subN = 3;
static final int N = subN*subN;
static final int N2 = N*N;
static final int VARS = N*N*N;
static int clauses = 0;
static ArrayList<String> DIMACS_CNF = new ArrayList();
static int[] solution = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, 9, -10, -11, -12, 13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20, 21, -22, -23, -24, -25, -26, -27, 28, -29, -30, -31, -32, -33, -34, -35, -36, -37, -38, -39, -40, -41, -42, 43, -44, -45, -46, -47, -48, -49, -50, 51, -52, -53, -54, -55, 56, -57, -58, -59, -60, -61, -62, -63, -64, -65, -66, -67, 68, -69, -70, -71, -72, -73, -74, -75, -76, -77, -78, -79, 80, -81, -82, -83, -84, -85, -86, -87, -88, 89, -90, 91, -92, -93, -94, -95, -96, -97, -98, -99, -100, -101, -102, -103, 104, -105, -106, -107, -108, -109, 110, -111, -112, -113, -114, -115, -116, -117, -118, -119, -120, -121, -122, 123, -124, -125, -126, -127, -128, -129, -130, -131, -132, -133, -134, 135, -136, -137, -138, 139, -140, -141, -142, -143, -144, -145, -146, 147, -148, -149, -150, -151, -152, -153, -154, -155, -156, -157, -158, -159, 160, -161, -162, -163, -164, -165, -166, -167, -168, 169, -170, -171, -172, -173, -174, -175, -176, 177, -178, -179, -180, 181, -182, -183, -184, -185, -186, -187, -188, -189, -190, -191, -192, -193, 194, -195, -196, -197, -198, -199, 200, -201, -202, -203, -204, -205, -206, -207, -208, -209, -210, -211, -212, -213, -214, 215, -216, -217, -218, -219, -220, -221, -222, -223, -224, 225, -226, -227, -228, 229, -230, -231, -232, -233, -234, -235, -236, 237, -238, -239, -240, -241, -242, -243, -244, -245, -246, -247, -248, 249, -250, -251, -252, -253, 254, -255, -256, -257, -258, -259, -260, -261, -262, -263, -264, -265, -266, -267, -268, 269, -270, -271, -272, -273, -274, -275, -276, -277, -278, 279, -280, -281, 282, -283, -284, -285, -286, -287, -288, -289, -290, -291, 292, -293, -294, -295, -296, -297, -298, -299, -300, -301, -302, -303, 304, -305, -306, 307, -308, -309, -310, -311, -312, -313, -314, -315, -316, -317, -318, -319, 320, -321, -322, -323, -324, -325, -326, -327, -328, 329, -330, -331, -332, -333, -334, -335, -336, -337, -338, -339, -340, -341, 342, -343, 344, -345, -346, -347, -348, -349, -350, -351, -352, -353, -354, 355, -356, -357, -358, -359, -360, -361, -362, -363, -364, -365, -366, -367, 368, -369, -370, -371, 372, -373, -374, -375, -376, -377, -378, 379, -380, -381, -382, -383, -384, -385, -386, -387, -388, -389, -390, -391, -392, -393, 394, -395, -396, -397, -398, -399, -400, -401, 402, -403, -404, -405, -406, -407, -408, 409, -410, -411, -412, -413, -414, -415, -416, 417, -418, -419, -420, -421, -422, -423, -424, -425, -426, -427, -428, -429, -430, -431, 432, -433, -434, -435, -436, -437, -438, 439, -440, -441, 442, -443, -444, -445, -446, -447, -448, -449, -450, -451, -452, -453, -454, 455, -456, -457, -458, -459, -460, -461, -462, -463, -464, 465, -466, -467, -468, -469, -470, -471, -472, -473, -474, -475, 476, -477, -478, 479, -480, -481, -482, -483, -484, -485, -486, -487, -488, 489, -490, -491, -492, -493, -494, -495, -496, -497, -498, -499, 500, -501, -502, -503, -504, -505, -506, -507, -508, -509, -510, 511, -512, -513, -514, -515, -516, -517, -518, 519, -520, -521, -522, -523, -524, -525, -526, -527, -528, -529, -530, 531, 532, -533, -534, -535, -536, -537, -538, -539, -540, -541, -542, -543, -544, -545, -546, -547, 548, -549, -550, 551, -552, -553, -554, -555, -556, -557, -558, -559, -560, -561, 562, -563, -564, -565, -566, -567, -568, 569, -570, -571, -572, -573, -574, -575, -576, -577, -578, -579, -580, -581, -582, -583, 584, -585, -586, -587, -588, -589, -590, 591, -592, -593, -594, -595, -596, 597, -598, -599, -600, -601, -602, -603, -604, -605, -606, 607, -608, -609, -610, -611, -612, -613, -614, -615, -616, -617, -618, 619, -620, -621, -622, -623, -624, -625, 626, -627, -628, -629, -630, -631, -632, -633, -634, -635, -636, -637, -638, 639, 640, -641, -642, -643, -644, -645, -646, -647, -648, 649, -650, -651, -652, -653, -654, -655, -656, -657, -658, -659, -660, -661, -662, -663, 664, -665, -666, -667, -668, -669, 670, -671, -672, -673, -674, -675, -676, -677, -678, -679, -680, -681, -682, 683, -684, -685, -686, -687, -688, 689, -690, -691, -692, -693, -694, 695, -696, -697, -698, -699, -700, -701, -702, -703, -704, 705, -706, -707, -708, -709, -710, -711, -712, -713, -714, -715, -716, 717, -718, -719, -720, -721, -722, -723, -724, -725, -726, -727, -728, 729, 0};

/**
 * Generate DIMACS CNF format and print any given SAT solution
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    // Generate DIMACS CNF format 
    addFacts();
    atLeastOneDigitInCell();
    eachDigitAtMostOnesInRow();
    eachDigitAtMostOnesInColumn();
    eachDigitAtMostOnesInSubGrid();
    print_DIMACS_CNF_format();
    
    // Print a SAT solution        
    printSATSolutionBoard(solution);
}    
    
/**
 * 
 * @param digit [1...N]
 * @param row [1...N]
 * @param column [1...N]
 * @return 
 */
private static int toVariable(int digit, int row, int column){
    return (N2*(digit-1) + N*(row-1) + (column-1) + 1);
}

private static void addFacts(){        
    // Facts
    DIMACS_CNF.add("c Pre-assigned entries");
    // Update the number of facts according to the number of added DIMACS CNF clauses
    int facts=17;
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(3, 2, 6) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(8, 2, 8) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(5, 2, 9) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(1, 3, 3) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(2, 3, 5) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(5, 4, 4) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(7, 4, 6) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(4, 5, 3) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(1, 5, 7) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(9, 6, 2) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(5, 7, 1) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(7, 7, 8) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(3, 7, 9) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(2, 8, 3) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(1, 8, 5) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(4, 9, 5) + " 0");
    DIMACS_CNF.add(toVariable(9, 9, 9) + " 0");
    clauses += facts; 
}

private static void atLeastOneDigitInCell(){        
    // Every cell contains at least one digit
    DIMACS_CNF.add("c Every cell contains at least one digit:");
    String str;
    for (int row = 1; row <= N; row++) {
        for (int column = 1; column <= N; column++) {                
            str = "";
            for (int digit = 1; digit <= N; digit++) {
                str += toVariable(digit,row,column) + " ";
            }
            DIMACS_CNF.add(str + "0");
            clauses++;
        }
    }
}

private static void eachDigitAtMostOnesInRow(){        
    // Each digit appears at most once in each row
    DIMACS_CNF.add("c Each digit appears at most once in each row:");
    for (int digit = 1; digit <= N; digit++) {
        for (int row = 1; row < N; row++) {
            for (int columnLow = 1; columnLow <= N-1; columnLow++) {
                for (int columnHigh = columnLow+1; columnHigh <= N; columnHigh++) {
                DIMACS_CNF.add("-" + toVariable(digit,row,columnLow) + " -" + toVariable(digit,row,columnHigh) + " 0");
                clauses++;
                }
            }                
        }
    }    
}

private static void eachDigitAtMostOnesInColumn(){
    // Each number appears at most once in each column
    DIMACS_CNF.add("c Each number appears at most once in each column:");
    for (int digit = 1; digit <= N; digit++) {
        for (int column = 1; column <= N; column++) {
            for (int rowLow = 1; rowLow <= N-1; rowLow++) {
                for (int rowHigh = rowLow+1; rowHigh <= N; rowHigh++) {
                    DIMACS_CNF.add("-" + toVariable(digit,rowLow,column) + " -" + toVariable(digit,rowHigh,column) + " 0");
                    clauses++;
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

private static void eachDigitAtMostOnesInSubGrid(){
    // Each number appears at most once in each sub-grid
    DIMACS_CNF.add("c Each number appears at most once in each sub-grid:");        
    for(int digit = 1; digit<=N; digit++){
        for(int subGridRow = 0; subGridRow <= subN-1; subGridRow++){
            for(int subRowLow = 1; subRowLow <= subN-1; subRowLow++){                    
                for(int columnSubGrid = 0; columnSubGrid <= subN-1; columnSubGrid++){
                    for(int subColumnLow = 1; subColumnLow <=subN; subColumnLow++){                          
                        for(int subRowHigh = subRowLow+1; subRowHigh <=subN; subRowHigh++){
                            for(int subColumHigh = 1; subColumHigh <= subN; subColumHigh++){
                                if(subColumnLow != subColumHigh){
                                    DIMACS_CNF.add("-" + toVariable(digit,(subN*subGridRow + subRowLow),(subN*columnSubGrid + subColumnLow)) + 
                                            " -" + toVariable(digit,(subN*subGridRow + subRowHigh),(subN*columnSubGrid + subColumHigh)) + " 0");
                                    clauses++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Print DIMACS CNF format 
 * @param variables 
 */
private static void print_DIMACS_CNF_format(){
    // Print DIMACS CNF format 
    System.out.println("==========================================");
    System.out.println("===== Beginning of DIMACS CNF format =====");
    System.out.println("==========================================");
    System.out.println("c digit range [1..." + N + "]");
    System.out.println("c row range: [1..." + N + "]");
    System.out.println("c column range: [1..." + N + "]");
    System.out.println("c board[digit][row][column]: variable");
    for (int digit = 1; digit <= N; digit++) {
        for (int row = 1; row <= N; row++) {
            for (int column = 1; column <= N; column++) {
                System.out.println("c board[" + digit + "][" + row + "][" + column + "]: " + toVariable(digit,row,column));                    
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("c #vars: " + VARS);
    System.out.println("c #clauses: " + clauses);
    System.out.println("p cnf " + VARS + " " + clauses);
    for (int i = 0; i < DIMACS_CNF.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(DIMACS_CNF.get(i));            
    }
    System.out.println("====================================");
    System.out.println("===== End of DIMACS CNF format =====");
    System.out.println("====================================");
    System.out.println("");
}

/**
 * Print resulting board based on a set of variables from a SAT solution
 * @param variables 
 */
private static void printSATSolutionBoard(int[] variables){
    int digit;
    int tmp;
    int row;
    int column;             
    
    int[][] tmpBoard = new int [N][N];
    for (row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < N; column++) {
            tmpBoard[row][column] = -1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
        if(variables[i] > 0){
            digit = (variables[i]-1)/N2;
            tmp = (variables[i]-1)%N2;
            row = tmp/N;
            column = tmp%N;
            tmpBoard[row][column] = digit;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("=======================");
    System.out.println("===== Given board =====");
    System.out.println("=======================");
    for (row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        System.out.print("   ");
        for (column = 0; column < N; column++) {
            System.out.print(((tmpBoard[row][column])>=0? (tmpBoard[row][column]+1):"-") + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("=======================");
}
```

}

Comment: Hey man I'm looking for an answer too! Message me, we can help each other out